# Python Requests: How are subsequent request.get handled exactly?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests

for i in range(3):
    g = requests.get('http://some-url/')
    print "request done"
```

**For each *request* that starts, does 'it' wait for the response to arrive(completely finished loading response) before doing another request?**

I have compared the time it takes to finish these requests with requests from my browser and the loading time is quite faster with *Requests*. I'm not sure if that is solely because of my browser executing javascript, loading images etc. or also because of how Requests works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, each request is done synchronously, so the next one will only start after the previous one finished. Quoting the [release notes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests):

> **0.13.0 (2012-05-29)**
>
> Removal of Requests.async in favor of [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `requests.get` is a synchronous operation. It waits for the page contents to be pulled into python as str.
The time difference you see is indeed due to the execution of javascipt and the fetching of additional files in the browser.

In firefox webconsole you can see the time it takes to download the page contents. This time should be roughly equal to the time you see with requests.